# How to select the last 3 words from a string in PL\SQL?

Tags: regex, plsql, plsqldeveloper, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

**I have a column with data like these:**

Professor Dr. Eigen Foster Criminalist

Student Natalie Portman Journalist

Victor Morgan Dentist

Swiss Based Dr. M. Muriel Bayes Jorunalist

**What I want to see is:**

Eigen Foster Criminalist

Natalie Portman Journalist

Victor Morgan Dentist

Muriel Bayes Jorunalist

I know I should do it somehow with regexp_substr, but I dont know how to use the $ for the starting position. So there could different number of words in a string, but i always need the last 3 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex `[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+$`

```
SELECT  regexp_substr('Professor Dr. Eigen Foster Criminalist', '[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+$')FROM dual;
```

- `$`    - means end of the string
- [^ ]+  - means at least one character but no spaces